# Angularjs directive callbackc

Tags: angularjs

how can I pass function to angularjs directive and execute it with parameters from the directive?

I am trying to render my directive with this "test-directive(cb="getDetails()") and it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say a directive is like this

```
angular.module('app', []).directive('testDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            callback: '&'
        }
    };
});
```

Then in html where you integrate the directive set the callback to a function which will be defined on your controller.

```
<test-directive callback="getDetails(newValue, oldValue)"/>
```

And in controller define `getDetails`

```
$scope.getDetails = function (newValue, oldValue) {
    // do whatever you want here
}
```

While you invoke your callback from directive then you have to call it like

```
$scope.callback({
    newValue: <a value>,
    oldValue: <another value>
});
```